# Uncountable Noun for Synonym of "Results" or "Records"

Tags: uncountable-nouns

I work a lot in programming where queries return 'N results'.
Is there an uncountable noun or identical singular and plural with a synonym of results or records?

The purpose of this would be to avoid creating various conditionals for things that contain more than one item. For example,

"0 results, 1 result, 2 results"

Comment: How about 'output'?

Comment: But queries do return countable results...

Comment: @Keepthesemind "Your query returned 2 output." - that sounds funny to me.

Comment: @Helmar --- If my query returned 2 deer --- it is a countable result with an uncountable noun.

Comment: @CodyG. That's because it is an uncountable noun. (Although '2 outputs' is fine.)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a noun that is also it own plural?

Comment: I suppose it might work! Or something like "Output: 2"

Comment: Why did you list deer as uncountable noun? It's not.

Comment: If you're doing what I think you are doing you may consider any of the following:  'result(s)', 'record(s)', 'number of results', 'number of records'.

Comment: The *deer* example works because *deer* is both singular and plural, not uncountable. And since you are using *N* (number), the concept *is* countable.

Comment: None here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Nouns_with_identical_singular_and_plural

Comment: 'Deer' is a count noun; it is (usually) an invariant noun (the forms of the plural and the singular are identical). It may possibly be used in a non-count way (as 'chicken' is) for the meat, but 'venison' is the usual choice. An example of a noun that isn't normally used in count form: 
"0 venison, 1 venison, 2 venison" (but note that 'Two venison, one plaice and one beef' might be heard in a restaurant kitchen).

Answer (score 0):

What about using the the word 'total' so that it removes the necessity to count. You would not have to pluralize the term total as in "1 total, 2 totals"

But, rather you could just use the term total as in your result/results, no matter how many, are summarized as 1 total, or 65 total, or 35,678 total.

You know that this stands for 'total number of results' without having to use a different term.